# How to use python map() to place inputs in separate lists

Tags: python, list

```
5
3 6
4 4
2 5
6 7
3 7
```

I am given these inputs. The first line is an integer Q, of which Q lines follow. Each line contains two integers L and R.

I would like to place all the L integers and R integers in their own lists.

```
arrL = [3,4,2,6,3]
```

```
arrR = [6,4,5,7,7]
```

Currently I am using a for loop to put the integers in these separate lists.

```
arrL = []
arrR = []
Q = int(input())
for i in range(Q):
    l, r = map(int, input().split(' '))
    arrL.append(l) 
    arrR.append(r)
    
print(arrL)
print(arrR)
```

Although this returns the correct lists, I was wondering if there was a more effective way to do this with the python map() function.

Many thanks

Comment: `arrL, arrR = zip(*(tuple(map(int, input().split(' '))) for _ in range(Q)))` would do. It's just very debatable whether that's really "better"…

Comment: lol, talk about readability

Comment: actually you implemented it very nicely, I would leave it as it is right now :)

Comment: One unrelated improvement is to change `split(' ')` to `split()` with no argument.  This will work on sequences of any kind of white space (i.e. it will handle cases that the current version doesn't).

Comment: @deceze The call to `tuple`, at least, is unnecessary. The `map` object is just as iterable as the `tuple`.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution

```
data="""3 6
4 4
2 5
6 7
3 7"""

lines=data.split("\n")
print(lines)

list1=[]
list2=[]
for line in lines:
    elements = line.split()
    list1.append(int(elements[0]))
    list2.append(int(elements[1]))
```